# How do I state the amount of money I have in a legal paper?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request

How do I state the amount of money I have in a legal paper? And what word should I use instead of 'money'?? Like: I have 10000 $ which equals 2000 £.

Comment: State the amount of your fortune in terms of its currency. _"I have 10,000USD,"_ e.g.

Comment: Note that if you decide to use a dollar, pound, or euro sign, for example, in English it's placed immediately before the amount: *...we have received €10 (£8.85)*. Because there are a number of *dollar* currencies, you might also want to specify them as such: *EC$15*. Other people prefer the ISO currency codes, whose spacing and position in amounts [isn't regulated by the ISO standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217#Position_of_ISO_4217_code_in_amounts).

Comment: What do you mean by "legal paper"? Depending on what it is, there may well be a style guide that tells you what the recommended format is. If it is a form or contract that someone else has asked you to fill in, it probably doesn't matter too much as long as the meaning is clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very liquid assets such as physical cash and/or bank accounts you can withdraw and have immediately should be described as *cash*: "I have $50,000 in cash." 
 E.g. $1000 in my mattress and $49,000 in a bank debit account.

Things like bonds, etc. should be described as such, "I have $50,000 in cash and $20,000 in an IRA and $30,000 savings bonds."  A good non-financial term for things other than cash is *savings* - so here you could say "I have $50,000 in cash and $50,000 in savings."

BUT, since this is a legal paper, you really should consult with a legal expert or at least discuss with the person who wants you to fill out the form.  Legal documents are in their own world with language and saying the wrong thing in the wrong way can have serious consequences.